# Android network security configuration: what is the difference between limiting the set of trusted CAs and certificate pinning?

Tags: android, security, ssl, networking, certificate-pinning

There are two ways to reduce the risk of trusting public CAs in Android apps: limiting the trusted set of certificates or implementing certificate pinning. It is quite straight forward to implement the two solutions with the help of the *network_security_config* file ([see: Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)). But I would like to understand more the difference between the two mechanisms? I assume, that limiting the set of trusted CAs is basically certificate pinning and using the hash for pinning is basically key pinning. Is that correct? Then I could consider the pro and cons described [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85209/difference-between-certificate-pinning-and-public-key-pinning), to decide for one or another.

See also [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)s guide about certificate pinning.

Comment: You are basically right as the Android documentation you mentioned state in the [Pin Certificates](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) section "Certificate pinning is done by providing a set of certificates by hash of the public key". So regarding two options Android docs are proposing limiting set of trusted pins is certificate pinning and using hashes is key pinning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @bmaciejm to confirm my assumption that **limiting set of trusted pins is certificate pinning and using hashes is key pinning**. Which means, that I can consider the pros and cons described [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85209/difference-between-certificate-pinning-and-public-key-pinning).